# How should I store this data in the database?

Tags: c#, json, sql-server, database

I read the data from the CSV files on Github and save it to my database. However, I have a lot of problems while using this data. I think my database model is inadequate for this. How should I store the data in this way in the database.

The database I use is SQL Server.

[Csv file i use](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv)

**My current database model**

I use a comma between the data for each day. I think it is not a healthy method.

**How can I make this better?**

[image]

*The json data I use at the front*

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "province": "",
    "country": "Afghanistan",
    "countryCode": "AF",
    "countryTrName": "Afghanistan",
    "latitude": 33,
    "longitude": 65,
    "confirmedData": [
      {
        "dateTime": "2020-01-22T00:00:00",
        "data": 0
      },
    "deathsData": [ bla ,bla .. ]
```

Comment: Create a separate table for your cases per Date data.

Comment: Doesn't that mean too much workload? Does it make sense to add a new table every day when we think of new data coming every day? @jason.kaisersmith

Comment: Storing comma delimited information in an RDBMS is always a bad idea. YOu want to normalise your data.

Comment: @Larnu 
Yes, I am aware that it is a bad idea, but considering the json model and the data I sent to the front, you chose such a way to avoid problems in terms of speed.

Comment: @MuhammetCaylak No, 1 table for the data and then add a new row for every day.  So you so little data that performance is not going to be an issue.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith 
I do not fully understand, do you have a chance to model

Comment: *"you chose such a way to avoid problems in terms of speed"* No I choose to avoid problems in the future; choosing to store delimited data will only cause problems down the line. Store it properly in the first place (by taking just a few more minutes when you load the data) can save you hours of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have issues indexing your data the way you have it now. To start, you don't seem to store actual dates of your measures taken. You also might want to expand your measures eventually and, say, add `recovered` or `false-positive`

I would suggest a model along these lines:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can model your DB as shown in this picture (You can change this to suit your exact needs).
[image: DB Model]

Then you add your countries and territories into the DB, which should be a one-off task.  Although you might need to add new ones if new countries/territories publish data which you don't currently have.
And for every new day you add a new Row into the ConfirmedCases table for the appropiate territory.

Comment: thank you for your interest

Answer (score 0):

I don't have in depth knowledge on your infrastructure, but I feel this is a data mutation issue. I'd say, as you are using a relational database, the first thing to do is normalize it. After that, if you need to get information many times a day, or even real time, I'd say, one good solution is to implement a message-broker service (such as rabbitmq) so you make sure your system will receive all data and will have the ability to process it without put the availability of your service in risk. Now, to store it, if you need to keep the history, I'd say a good solution would be to create something similar to a log table, taking advantage of a normalized database (as I said at the begin) you will be able to create a table just to store the history records, and if you don't need this history, I think the same idea works, but instead of creating new records, you just update the existing ones. If you need both, I'd say to create two tables on database, one to store the history data, and other to store the consolidated data.

Comment: thank you for your interest

Answer (score 0):

Generally databases handle simple operations such as accessing, adding or deleting rows in tables more quickly than manipulating data within a field.

To this end if you have data that is regularly changing, such as your daily confirmedData and deathsData fields then these should be added as a new row each day.

You can avoid duplication of static data (your country data) by placing it within a separate table to your confirmedData and confirmedDeaths data, you then just need an indexed link back to your Country table.

By placing your dynamic data into a separate table you can then add a date field. This would then make searching or collating data for a given date or date period easier to implement.

Comment: thank you for your interest